# python 'print' statement and range

Tags: python

I didn't understand the following two cases:

```
from __future__ import print_function
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(raw_input())
    print(*range(1,n+1), sep='')
```

if n is 3

```
output:123
```

And in second case with statement,

```
print(range(1,n+1), sep='')

output:[1, 2, 3]
```

Didn't understand the function of "*" , is it related to range or print statement?

Comment: `print(range(1,2+1), sep='')` will return `range(1, 3)`

Comment: The *(star) operator in a function call unpacks list/tuples etc. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-parameters for a larger answer covering it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the [Argument Unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) feature in Python.

Here is a quick example:

```
def f(a,b,c):
    print(a,b,c)

f(1,2,3)
f(*[1,2,3])
```

So `print(*(1,2,3))` is equivalent to `print(1,2,3)`

Answer (score 0):

Range returns a tuple, which gets expanded by the * in the function call. It's equivalent to print (1, 2, 3, sep=' '). The * is used to unpack unnamed args. Since they are always passed first keyword args are still allowed as long as any arg doesn't get 2 values.

Answer (score 0):

Please see python's [Expressions reference](https://docs.python.org/dev/reference/expressions.html#calls)

The list's values are being unpacked by the * operator. Here's the quote from the documentation:

> If the syntax *expression appears in the function call, expression
>   must evaluate to an iterable. Elements from this iterable are treated
>   as if they were additional positional arguments; if there are
>   positional arguments x1, ..., xN, and expression evaluates to a
>   sequence y1, ..., yM, this is equivalent to a call with M+N positional
>   arguments x1, ..., xN, y1, ..., yM.